# Python get data from API using Requests failed

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have been trying to use requests to pull json data with client id and api key, but it won't work.

Here is the info I received from IT:

```
Request: 
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.abc.com/def' \ 
--header 'clientid: testuser' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'apikey: testapikey1234' \
--header 'dc_session: UUID' \
--header 'dc_transaction_id: UUID'
```

I wrote the following code in python

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.abc.com/def'

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'clientid': 'testuser', 'apikey': 'testapikey1234', 'dc_session': 'UUID', 'dc_transaction_id': 'UUID'}

response = requests.get(url, verify = False, headers = headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Unfortunately the code returns 401 status code, with the error message:
`{'error': {'type': 'INVALID_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER', 'message': 'Unauthorized. Missing or invalid clientID.'}}`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If the curl request is working, this might be helpful to checkout.
[Convert curl to Python requests](https://reqbin.com/req/python/c-xgafmluu/convert-curl-to-python-requests)

Comment: @SiddharthaDutta Thanks, this is helpful. I converted the code using this tool but still received the same error. I also tried to run the CURL in command window: `curl --location --request GET “https://api.abc.com/def“ --header “clientid: testuser” --header “Accept: application/json” --header “apikey: testapikey1234” --header “dc_session: UUID” --header “dc_transaction_id: UUID”` but received the same error: `{
  "error" : {
     "type"  : "UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT",
     "message" : "Unauthorized. Missing or invalid API key credentials."
     }
}`

Comment: error shows `Missing or invalid API key credentials` so you use wrong `apikey`. Maybe you should login to `abc.com` to generate new `apikey`